# Leetcode 867. Transpose Matrix; Debug; Generate list

Tags: arrays, list, matrix, transpose

I meet a weird bug in Leetcode 867. Transpose Matrix.

The question is

Given a matrix A, return the transpose of A.

The transpose of a matrix is the matrix flipped over it's main diagonal, switching the row and column indices of the matrix.

Example 1:

Input: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Output: [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
Example 2:

Input: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
Output: [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]

The code gives the right out is

```
`res = [[None] * len(A) for _ in range(len(A[0]))]
#res = [[None] * len(A)] * len(A[0]) # why this doesn't work

for r, row in enumerate(A):
    for c, val in enumerate(row):
        res[c][r] = val

return res`
```

My solution is

```
`res = [[None] * len(A)] * len(A[0]) # why this doesn't work

for r, row in enumerate(A):
    for c, val in enumerate(row):
        res[c][r] = val

return res`
```

which gives the input and the output as 
Your input
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
Output
[[3,6],[3,6],[3,6]]
Expected
[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]

**The only difference between my solution and the right answer is **

```
`res = [[None] * len(A) for _ in range(len(A[0]))]
res = [[None] * len(A)] * len(A[0]) # why this doesn't work`
```

**Why the second line doesn't work? **

`[[None] * len(A) for _ in range(len(A[0]))] == [[None] * len(A)] * len(A[0])`
 returns `True`

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```
res = [[None] * len(A) for _ in range(len(A[0]))]
```

creates a list containing len(A[0]) different lists, whereas

```
res = [[None] * len(A)] * len(A[0]) # why this doesn't work
```

creates a list containing len(A[0]) references to the same list, so that modifying a value in one of them modifies it in all of them.

See [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) among others ...